# Group of left-floated fixed-width divs within a container - strange behaviour (irregular break to next row?)

Tags: html, css, css-float, row, css-selectors

I have a group of divs that I want to arrange in 4 columns. I've created css rules such that the first item has a left and right margin, the following two only a right margin, and the fourth element in a row to have no left or right margin:

```
article.participants-thumbnail {
    width: 180px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 73px;
    margin-bottom: 73px;
}

article.participants-thumbnail:nth-of-type(4n) {
    margin-right: 0;
}

article.participants-thumbnail:nth-of-type(4n+1) {
    margin-left: 18px;
    margin-right: 73px;
}
```

It worked perfectly but for some reason now, the 5th (1st item of row 2) item is on its own row completely.

It works properly in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/waffl/dJEYF/embedded/result/

Thank you!

--

**Update**

As per the comment recommendation, the following css works:

```
article.participants-thumbnail {
    width: 180px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 73px;
    margin-bottom: 73px;
}

article.participants-thumbnail:nth-of-type(4n) {
    margin-right: 0;
}

article.participants-thumbnail:nth-of-type(4n+1) {
    margin-left: 18px;
    margin-right: 73px;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `clear:both;` to the last element in each row?

Comment: Ah, good thinking, clear: both; needed to be added to the 'first' element though and it works perfectly!

Comment: @artoh - maybe post it as an answer if you'd like the reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when floating div's behave strangely, it's because a `clear: both;` style needs to be added between each logical row of floating elements.